# Making a dropdown menu thats width is decided upon the amount of sections within it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a dropdown menu for a site and i am trying to change the width of the parent div (.drop-down) depending on how many sections that instance of the element has within it. There are a total of 7 instances of .drop-down each containing different amounts of sections no more than 3 but at least 1. Here is my code where am i going wrong?

```
    $('.drop-down').each(function(index) {
    var numSections = $(this).find('section').length;

        if (numSections = 1) {
            $('.drop-down').css('width','300px');
        }

        else if (numSections = 2) {
            $('.drop-down').css('width','600px');
        }

        else
            $('.drop-down').css('width','840px');
    });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is fine, for a start. You explain what you want to do, and supply the code to achieve it. However, you forget to tell us what the problem is. What happens on the page, and how does it deviate from how you would expect it to behave?

Comment: Sorry basically it is always returning the final value of 840px for the width. It doesnt seem to be finding how many sections are within the instance of .drop-down and specifying the width accordingly.

Comment: I will implement your solution and get back to you. Thankyou for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Nix Thanks again. Now implementing it.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if it works or not (and accept/vote up if it does) ;)

Comment: @Nix now it is taking the the first if statement and ignoring the rest making all the widths to 300px

Comment: Eh, that's strange. I think we need to see your markup. My jsfiddle seems to be working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/MFfgj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.drop-down').each(function(index)
{
    var numSections = $(this).find('section').length;

    if (numSections == 1) {
        $(this).css('width', 300);
    }
    else if (numSections == 2) {
        $(this).css('width', 600);
    }
    else if (numSections == 3){
        $(this).css('width', 840);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which class of `.drop-down` you are targetting. Try `$(this)`:

```
$('.drop-down').each(function(index) {
    var numSections = $(this).find('section').length;

        if (numSections = 1) {
            $(this).css('width','300px');
        }

        else if (numSections = 2) {
            $(this).css('width','600px');
        }

        else
            $(this).css('width','840px');
    });
```

You may also declare the new width as an integer instead of a string, like so:

```
$(this).css('width',840);
```

EDIT: Here's a basic jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MFfgj/